# PowerShell Slack Function

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell function to call a Slack webhook. I took the function from a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4fyrwg/slack_notifications_from_powershell/), but the function seems to be failing with a parse error. Also I removed the webhook.

Here is the code:

```
function Send-SlackMessage {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]$Text,
        $Url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx",
        # Parameters below are optional and will fall back to the default
        $Username = "XXXXXXX",
        $Channel = "XXXXXXX",
        $Emoji = "XXXXXX"
    )

    $body = @{ text=$Text; channel=$Channel; username=$Username; icon_emoji=$Emoji } | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $Url -Body $body
}
```

and the error:

```
At line:12 char:67
+ ... y = @{ text=$Text; channel=$Channel; username=$Username; icon_emoji=$ ...
+
Missing '=' @{ text=$Text; channel=$Channel; username=$Username; icon_emoji=$ ...

The hash literal was incommplete.
 + CategoryInfo              :ParserError (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
 + FillyQualifiedErrorId     : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

Comment: Just an FYI but there is a PowerShell module that is available for this now: [PSSlack](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSSlack/1.0.1). Code is found [here](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSlack/).

Answer (score 1):

Where's the function name? You are missing a comma after the 2nd param, and have an extra comma after the last param.

```
function whatever ()
{
param (
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]$Text,
     $Url="https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx",
     # Parameters below are optional and will fall back to the default
        $Username = "XXXXXXX",
        $Channel = "XXXXXXX",
        $Emoji = "XXXXXX"
    )

    $body = @{ text=$Text; channel=$Channel; username=$Username; icon_emoji=$Emoji } | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $Url -Body $body
}
```

Comment: I guess maybe I have the function formatting incorrect? I did check my original code and the commas in the parameters are correct. sry, working on a VM that doesn't have copy/paste available. It seems that the error is coming from the "body" part of the function. I did change the formatting of the function call.